# Производная в книгах Кнута - Искусство Программирования

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Здравствуйте. Пожалуйста кто читал книги Дональда Кнута - Искусство программирования, подскажите есть ли там такая задача, которая как раз и решается в самой книге, найти производную функции? Примерно так, ты даешь любое выражение/функцию и программа возвращает тебе производную. Пожалуйста помогите, очень надо узнать в каком именно томе эта задача описывается, в какой главе и т.д.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, не помню я такого у Кнута. Кстати, вас интересует вычисление производной аналитически или численно?

Comment: мне интересно именно то что у Кнута, а как у него, я, к сожалению, не знаю(((

Comment: Где-то был пример, в разделе про связные списки, что ли

Comment: Но там, разумеется, не было разбора строки в объектное представление

Comment: [вот письмо](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/calc), где Кнут рассказывает об мат.анализе, используя `O(n)` нотацию. [strong] Производная определяется из формулы: `f(x+ε)=f(x)+f'(x)ε+O(ε²)` или более общая: `f(x+ε)=f(x)+f'(x)ε+o(ε)`

Comment: нет, мне сказали что там должно быть и решение данной задачи

Comment: а возможна ли реализация данной задачи на c++? Чтоб программа получала выражение/функцию и дала на выход его производную

Comment: На С++ возможна реализация ЛЮБОЙ РАЗРЕШИМОЙ задачи :) Но если вас интересует именно аналитическое вычисление производной - то на 99% уверен, что в *Искусстве программирования* этого нет.

Comment: ну ладно)) а может где-то в другом месте вы видели пошаговый разбор скажем, реализации этого на c++?

Comment: Ну по сути вы хотите переписать заново кусок Wolfram Mathematica. Нужен синтаксический анализ, разбор выражений на простейшие составляющие, потом применение правил вычисления производных для составных выражений, потом упрощение полученного результата...

Comment: ну да, это и нужно

Comment: если вас не интересует именно Кнут, то это слишком обширный вопрос: что именно вас интересует: правила как производные вычислять для алгебраических выражений? как текст распознавать? (просто) как вообще с выражениями в с++ работать? (как реализовать Maple подмножество). Задача безусловно решаемая

Comment: @jfs ну как я понял у Кнута такого нету. Скорее всего мне понадобиться все выше перечисленное вами...просто мне интересно может кто-то в какой то книге или статье сделал уже такое

Comment: @Tiber_Septim ответы объёмом с книгу — это не по теме на Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tiber_Septim, если станет совсем скучно и нечем будет заняться можно покопаться в исходниках [SymPy (Python)](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html) ;-)

Comment: @jfs, `вот письмо...` — это интегрирование численным методом первого порядка. Его описывал ещё Эйлер, задолго до Кнута.

Comment: @Arhad не путайте *определение* величины (что я привёл) и способ её вычисления (численные методы тут ни при чём).  Big O нотацию не знаю кто придумал, но сомневаюсь что Эйлер, да и не важно кто первым производную определил через эту нотацию. Я комментировал вопрос "производная в книгах Кнута", а не вопрос "производная в книгах Эйлера".